# Will Phonegap current version work on BlackBerry OS version 5?

Tags: blackberry, cordova

I am new to mobile development and I was wondering if the applications I develop using phonegap will work correctly on Blackberry OS 5 since they don't support it yet. I won't need any fancy features in my app and wanted to use phonegap to develop for Android, IPhone and Blackberry. But of course I am having problems with the different versions of Blackberry OS just like everyone else.

Thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but to run on OS version 4.x you have to target the PhoneGap BlackBerry application, while to run on OS version 5 or 6 you need to target [BlackBerry Widgets / WebWorks](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/31930982/Getting-Started-with-PhoneGap-(BlackBerry-Widgets)) -- the same application may work on both if you use compatible features, but you'll need two different builds, as though they were two different kinds of phone.

Answer (score 3):

I had a chance to test this once. I have put my Phonegap application on 5.0 and observed how it behaves. Application has launched properly. But i Observed following issues.

1. HTML5 is supported but localStorage and sessionStorage is not supported.You need to find an alternative.
2. HTML Page transition is too slow. End used will certainly not accept the performance.
3. Few jQueryMobile API's don't work.
4. You cannot be sure that page will be viewed same as you see in 6.0+. Few elements get distorted.
5. You need to test each and every UI element and see if it is working proper.For example datepicker displays date on right side of the page instead of left
6. Few PhoneGap API's don't work or they crash.For example API to launch camera crashes.

After observing above issues i felt that even if phonegap is supported in 5.0 it doesn't make big sense.

Comment: my phonegap 2.8.1 app is having just simple navigation of page using href tag. so simple app crashes on bb 6.0. it uses session storage and  ajax loading for one time only.

Comment: I am developing simple phonegap 2.8.1 bb app.
I have tested it on device torch 9800 with bb os 6.0 but it crashes when I navigate from one page to another page by href tag.
I am only using ajax loading & session storage at page loaded only once.
So simple app crashes on bb.

Comment: To navigate from one page to another you can use window.location.replace("next_page.html"). sessionStorage is not a problem on 6.0 even ajax call should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Now the support for earlier versions of BlackBerry has been withdrawn from Cordova 3.0 onwards, which in turn supports BlackBerry 10 only. Refer the following link for more details.

[PhoneGap - BlackBerry Support](http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/05/16/cordova-will-no-longer-support-bb/)

Thanks,
prodeveloper